# CircularGauge parent reference error

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickextras

when exiting application developed under Qt, I am getting following error:

```
file:///C:/Qt/5.10.0/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/Control.qml:90:
ReferenceError: parent is not defined
```

from component defined as simply as this:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Item {
    id:root

    CircularGauge {
        anchors.centerIn: root
    }
}
```

If line

```
anchors.centerIn: root
```

is removed, then there's no error. I am pretty sure that error is produced whenever CircularGauge somehow references parent, although setting

```
parent:root
```

in gauge does not help. Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: The example works fine for me on Windows 10 with MSVC2017, with both the 5.11 branch and a pre-built 5.9.4.

Comment: Is this the whole snippet, or did you leave something out? The error seems similar to those in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63729.

Comment: This is the whole file.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the control source. A bad file? A buggy version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Desktop Qt 5.10.0 MinGW 32bit. When changed to v5.8, application exits without error and this is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `anchors.centerIn: parent` instead if `anchors.centerIn: root`.